# Design pattern request for event queue entries

Tags: java, design-patterns

I really need your help regarding a design pattern which I can use, because right now I can't think of the best solution.

I need something which can accomplish the following thing. 
Currently I have 3 objects :

`NotificationOne.java`

`NotificationTwo.java`

`NotificationThree.java`

Each one, represents basically the same thing, but they have nothing in common when it comes to fields/attributes.

These are actually some JSON's which I will map into objects, when they arrive via a JMS Queue.

Now, what I really need to do, is to transform these 3 objects to a common object, by interpreting their fields in a particular way for each one. Easy to done 'till now.

The real question is, what would be the best design pattern to apply, considering that in time, there will be more and more types of Notifications which will have to be transformed from something to a common object.

The flow of things will be something like this :

-JSON gets in the queue

-I will map the JSON to a POJO

-Pass the POJO to a possible factory, which will have to deal with each type of Notification class, so it can transform it into something which we'll call it **CommonNotification**.

-**CommonNotification** has to be stored into DB

-A particular field of CommonNotification has to be used as a notification payload.

Based on this flow, what's the best pattern which I can use.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about mapping JSON to a POJOs that implement a common interface with a method like `convertToCommonNotification()`?

Comment: Dive to JSON serialization.

Comment: Is this a good practice ? I mean,  why should I make the POJO itself responsible of this task.. isn't better to have something else doing this ? I think a POJO has to remain a POJO. @nikpon what do you mean by diving to serialization ? Thanks guys for answering

Comment: you can use Command pattern for event queue management. And Decorator pattern to decorate base notification type as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You're saying the conversion depends on the type of notification? Like zapl said, in that case, I would create a common interface and let the three notification classes do the conversion. The design is very simple. Everybody who creates a new notification, knows that it should implement the interface and hence, knows that a conversion should be done.

Strictly theoretically speaking you're right in that a POJO should be a POJO, but I wouldn't make my design any more complicated than needed in this case. An interface and polymorphism is the way to go here.

Next to that, creating a common notification doesn't have any side effects in the system. So it's not that your POJO is modifying any system state. It just has some logic which is very POJO specific. It belongs in the POJO.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Decorator pattern.

> The ConcreteDecorator just adds responsibilities to the original
>   Component.

You can have different concrete decorator for different output but the responsibilities from your original component will be there in every output if that's what you want.

See http://www.oodesign.com/decorator-pattern.html